# class not adding back to input with iterative function Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a simple function that checks whether or not all inputs are filled or empty for inputs with a particular class. The issue I am having is that the function runs correctly once, but doesn't re-add the hide class if the input is empty.

```
   <i class="text-success fa fa-check hide-info-complete" id="info-check"></i>
   <input class="info-input" name="school" />
   <input class="info-input" name="bus" />


 function checkInfoFormOnBlur() {
        var form_complete_check = document.getElementById("info-check");
        $('.info-input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === '') {
                form_complete_check.classList.add("hide-info-complete-check-mark");
            } else if ($(this).val() !== '') {
                form_complete_check.classList.remove("hide-info-complete-check-mark");
            }
        });
    }

setInterval(function(){ checkInfoFormOnBlur(); }, 3000);
```

If both fields have a value, it works -- but it doesn't work when one input is empty after the first run. the hide-info-complete class does not get sent back to the i tag.

How can I recursively check whether or not all inputs are filled or empty with setInterval and properly remove the hide-info-complete class when an input no longer has a value.

Comment: You are doing it wrong.... It is only going to be what the last item in the array is.

Comment: I apologize, I'm kind of tired. I just added info-input class to the example inputs.

Comment: `if ($('.info-input').filter(function(){ return !this.value.trim(); }).length > 0) {}` will tell you if any input does not have a value

Comment: Also as a side note; you are intermixing jQuery lookups with vanilla lookups, as well as the different attribute/property access strategies.  For clarity, stick with doing it one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

- If the elements start out as blank, put the class on the element to start with so it is hidden
- Use an event handler to handle when the value changes, rather than an interval

  - When the value changes, toggle the class so that it only has the class if any of the inputs are blank

```js
var $infoCheck = $('#info-check');
var $inputs = $('.info-input').on('input', function(){
  $infoCheck.toggleClass(
    'hide-info-complete-check-mark',
    $inputs.filter(function(){ return !this.value.trim(); }).length > 0
  );
});
```

```css
.hide-info-complete-check-mark { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="text-success fa fa-check hide-info-complete hide-info-complete-check-mark" id="info-check">Info Check</i>
<input class="info-input" name="school" />
<input class="info-input" name="bus" />
```

Comment: `hide-info-complete` is on the element so not sure what the first bullet point is about.

Comment: @epascarello `hide-info-complete` !== `hide-info-complete-check-mark`, which is what is being toggled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the check. Your code only is looking at the last index and that determines what happens. And it makes no sense to be doing it on a timer.

Add event listeners to the elements and I use filter to find any elements that are unchecked.

```js
var inputs = $(".info-check")
var check = $("#info-check")
inputs.on("change", function() {
  var isValid = inputs.filter(function(input) {
    return this.value.trim().length === 0
  }).length === 0
  check.toggleClass('hide-info-complete', !isValid)
}).change()
```

```css
.hide-info-complete {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<i class="text-success fa fa-check hide-info-complete" id="info-check"></i>

<input class="info-check" name="school" />
<input class="info-check" name="bus" />
```

Doing it without jQuery

```js
var inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".info-check"))
var check = document.querySelector("#info-check")

var checkValid = function () {
  var isValid = inputs.every(function(input) {
    return input.value.trim().length > 0
  })
  check.classList.toggle('hide-info-complete', !isValid)
}

inputs.forEach(function (input) {
  input.addEventListener("change", checkValid)
})
```

```css
.hide-info-complete {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<i class="text-success fa fa-check hide-info-complete" id="info-check"></i>

<input class="info-check" name="school" />
<input class="info-check" name="bus" />
```

and with HTML5 which requires no JavaScript at all.

```css
form:invalid #info-check{  
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form>
  <i class="text-success fa fa-check" id="info-check"></i>

  <input class="info-check" name="school" required />
  <input class="info-check" name="bus" required />
</form>
```